# Use javascript to rename file before upload

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this list of forms like so:

`var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('uploadImage');`

each item in this list look like this:

```
<form method=​"post" action=​"/​upload" enctype=​"multipart/​form-data" id=​"f_x" class=​"uploadImage">

​    <input type=​"file" id=​"u_x">​
    <input type=​"submit" value=​"Submit" id=​"s_x">​

</form>​
```

where `x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`

**How do I loop through this list and do two things:**

1 - Rename the file name

2 - Submit the form for uploading the file

I looked for many resources online like this one: https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-file's-name-when-it's-uploaded-via-html-form,  all of them are using **Jquery** , I need it in **javascript**

**update** :-

I figured out how to get to the input value of each form

`forms[0].elements[0]` this will return the first input of the first form on the list

`forms[0].elements[0].value` this output the value of the file input

Comment: Are you uploading file using node js ?

Comment: @SachinShah no just javascript and python-flask as a backend

Comment: Did you want to use AJAX? Or using native `<form>` elements.

Comment: ok then , so add python also in technology

Comment: @Twisty i can use Ajax but i used `<form>` it's much simpler

Comment: @za001a hard to say just yet. Using AJAX will help ensure you know exactly what is being sent to your Upload script, including the name etc. The `.submit()` callback could potentially submit the data before it's changed. Should be able to make it work properly either way.

Comment: @SachinShah yes i use python as a backend but i don't want to use server resources in renaming files , i rather use the client side :)

Comment: @za001a would each form be submitted at the same time or individually?

Comment: @Twisty yes at the same time so i understand i need to loop through each form and submit it one by one but inside the same for loop  :)

Comment: What's so important about changing the file name before uploading them to the server? You can't trust client side validation anyway so this question doesn't make any sense

Comment: @AlonEitan reducing the waste of server resources , this process will save lot's of time i can just make a simple function on the server side to validate it instead of pulling data from 3 sql tables then rename every file for each user

Comment: @za001a what do you want to rename them to?

Comment: @Twisy it will depend on the user's details and time stamp , that would be the easy part

Comment: @za001a your example does not include that detail. To better help, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It has all the details required though it doesn't matter what variable I will change the file to the question is how?

Comment: @za001a ok. So you want a JavaScrip solution? That works the same way as the jQuery you linked to? Are you unable to use jQuery?

Comment: Not quite sure what jQuery code does but yes I think , I don't use jQuery  just JavaScript

Answer (score 26):

So here is the code you linked to, and I will break it down a bit after. A lot of it is vanilla javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    initImageUpload();

    function initImageUpload() {
        $("#btn-submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var everlive = new Everlive({
                appId: "",
                scheme: "https"
            });

            // construct the form data and apply new file name
            var file = $('#image-file').get(0).files[0];

            var newFileName = file.filename + "new";
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file, newFileName);


            $.ajax({
                url: everlive.files.getUploadUrl(), // get the upload URL for the server
                success: function(fileData) {
                    alert('Created file with Id: ' + fileData.Result[0].Id); // access the result of the file upload for the created file
                    alert('The created file Uri is available at URL: ' + fileData.Result[0].Uri);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert('error ' + e.message);
                },
                // Form data
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

As is mentioned, this uses jQuery `$.ajax()` to create an AJAX POST to the server with new FormData where the name of the file has been modified. The new FormData is then sent to the server instead of the HTML Form data.

So, when the button is clicked to submit the form, this event is prevented.

`var file = $('#image-file').get(0).files[0];`

This is then used to select the `<input>` element in jQuery and then collect the `files` info from the element.

`var file = document.getElementById("image-file").files[0];`

This can be done with JavaScript. Largely the rest of the script would be unchanged, except for the initialization and sending of POST Data via AJAX.

It might be best to create a function that you send the form to and it can then return the new form data with new name. As you did not want to provide an MCVE, it's hard to give you an example since it's not clear how the data for the new name would be create or gathered from.

```
function nameFile(inEl, newName){
  var file = inEl.files[0];
  var results = new FormData();
  results.append('file', file, newName);
  return results;
}

function sendFile(url, formData){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", url);
  request.send(formData);
}

sendFile("/​upload", nameFile(document.getElementById("file-image"), "UserFile-" + new Date().now() + ".jpg"));
```

Another issue is if you have multiple forms, and multiple submit buttons, which one will trigger all the items to get uploaded? Either way, you'd have to iterate each form (maybe with a `for()` loop) collect the form data from each, update the name, and submit each one, most likely via AJAX.

Hope this helps.

Comment: props to you for writing such a comprehensive answer! +1